# Keyboard and Combobox suggestappend

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I would like combo box suggest append to work with a C# keyboard.

I have a keyboard i created with buttons that insert text into the combobox but it doesnt suggest anything when i do this.

First time here, any help would be appreciated.

here is some code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Text = "C";
}
```

combobox is set to autocompletemode = suggestappend and autocompletesource = listitems

when i click button1 then i would like the combobox to suggest items starting with 'C'

This works fine when using the keyboard but not when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why nobody told you the answer to this. I know it's old like hell... but the answer is `ComboBox1.DroppedDown = True`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Text = "C";
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = True;
}
```